# What is the expected image for this SVG file?

Tags: svg, alignment

I am trying to make a plot with each data point labelled on the x-axis with a text string written vertically. It all seems to work as expected except that the labels appear to be shifted left by one unit. I thought it was a bug in my c++ generating code but finally made a test case. In the following, I wanted the red and blue lines to underline the text but they
seem to go through the text. The green lines, offset by one, appear where 
I thought the others should be relative to the text. What do I need to do here?  The center of rotation does appear as expected. Thanks. Right now I'm just kluging the code to fix the offset but would like to fix it lol.

```
<svg style="overflow: hidden; -moz-user-select: none; cursor: default; position: relative; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" version="1.1" height="100"><desc> test foo</desc>
<rect fill-opacity="1" stroke-width="1" stroke-opacity="1" style="" stroke="#00808080" fill="#00808080" ry="0" rx="0" r="0" height="100" width="100" y="0" x="0"></rect> <g fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="1000" />
<path d="M0 0 L50 0 " stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
<text  font-weight="normal" font-size="5" font-family="Verdana" fill="#00ffffff" y="10" x="10" style="dominant-baseline: alphabetic; text-anchor: start;">unidentified</text>
<text transform="rotate(90,10,10)"  font-weight="normal" font-size="5" font-family="Verdana" fill="#00ffffff" y="10" x="10" style="dominant-baseline: alphabetic; text-anchor: start;">unidentified</text>
<text transform="rotate(45,10,10)"  font-weight="normal" font-size="5" font-family="Verdana" fill="#00ffffff" y="10" x="10" style="dominant-baseline: alphabetic; text-anchor: start;">unidentified</text>
<path d="M0 10 L100 10 " stroke="red" stroke-width=".1"/>
<path d="M0 11 L100 11 " stroke="green" stroke-width=".1"/>
<path d="M10 0 L10 100 " stroke="blue" stroke-width=".1"/>
<path d="M9 0 L9 100 " stroke="green" stroke-width=".1"/>

</svg>
```

Comment: This is working as expected. If you don't want the lines to overlap your text you need to move them +1 from where you're positioning the text.

Comment: Thanks. Is the general rule well known? The example I could find of baseline alphabetic put lines under the text not through it and again the center of rotation appears where I thought the baseline should be. It just looks like text and line coordinates differ.

Comment: To clarify, on my viewer the center of rotation is apparently around the intersection of the red and blue lines rather than the shifted green lines. So I guess the issue is the baseline with respect to the text not line and text coord offset.

Comment: Again, this is working as expected - the transform is happening with a transform origin of 10,10 - as you specify in the transform. Why do you expect the transform origin to be at 11,9?

Comment: I guess the question is where the baseline is supposed to be wrt the text. This is a huge source of confusion when the text is only one unit in size and the graph labels are all off by one lol. The illustrations I have seen suggest the baseline is below most of the text except for any descenders. This one pixel offset appears to mess up the scaling. Is this documented anywhere? What seems to happen is that the baseline moves up the text as the size decreases which does not sound right. In this example it is about .2 up the text.

Comment: All I can tell you is read the SVG 1.1 spec. The behavior follows the spec.

Comment: The position of the baseline depends on the size? lol. If the text is one unit high, in my verson of eog anyway, the baseline is above the text.